# SVG created with CorelDraw won't show text on iOS

Tags: ios, svg

I have a bunch of SVG images created with various software (Inkscape, CorelDraw X7), and I found that my SVGs made in **CorelDRAW X7** didn't show the text in iOS devices.

http://thepotentpixel.com/svg-bug/

I have an example of a working image and non-working image in the link above. If you open it on an iOS device using Safari or Chrome, the bottom image's numbers disappear, but the top image they display.

Any idea why?

Both use a `<text>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottom SVG uses an SVG font, which is not supported in Chrome (and I guess Safari).

If we remove the `<font>` element, and the reference to it in `@font-face` the SVG displays fine in Chrome.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Creator: CorelDRAW X7 -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xml:space="preserve"
   width="400px"
   height="100px"
   version="1.1"
   style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd"
   viewBox="0 0 4000 1000"
   id="svg2"
   >

           
           <defs
     id="defs4"><style
       type="text/css"
       id="style383">
    @font-face { font-family:"Arial";}
    .str1 {stroke:#999999;stroke-width:29.9981}
    .str0 {stroke:#CCCCCC;stroke-width:29.9981}
    .str2 {stroke:blue;stroke-width:19.9975}
    .fil0 {fill:none}
    .fil1 {fill:black}
    .fil2 {fill:#009933;fill-rule:nonzero}
    .fnt0 {font-weight:normal;font-size:200.096px;font-family:'Arial'}
   </style></defs><g
     id="Слой_x0020_1"><metadata
       id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer" /><line
       class="fil0 str0"
       x1="60"
       y1="652"
       x2="3950"
       y2="652"
       id="line387" /><line
       class="fil0 str1"
       x1="264"
       y1="583"
       x2="264"
       y2="733"
       id="line389" /><line
       class="fil0 str1"
       x1="3014"
       y1="583"
       x2="3014"
       y2="733"
       id="line391" /><line
       class="fil0 str1"
       x1="3374"
       y1="583"
       x2="3374"
       y2="733"
       id="line393" /><line
       class="fil0 str1"
       x1="3726"
       y1="583"
       x2="3726"
       y2="733"
       id="line395" /><text
       x="149"
       y="953"
       class="fil1 fnt0"
       id="text397">17</text>
<text
       x="2918"
       y="953"
       class="fil1 fnt0"
       id="text399"
       style="font-size:200.09599304px;font-weight:normal;fill:#000000;font-family:Arial">77</text>
<text
       x="3290"
       y="953"
       class="fil1 fnt0"
       id="text401"
       style="font-size:200.09599304px;font-weight:normal;fill:#000000;font-family:Arial">80</text>
<text
       x="3625"
       y="953"
       class="fil1 fnt0"
       id="text403"
       style="font-size:200.09599304px;font-weight:normal;fill:#000000;font-family:Arial">83</text>
<line
       class="fil0 str2"
       x1="264"
       y1="575"
       x2="264"
       y2="15.483364"
       id="line405"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:10;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:30.00000009, 30.00000009;stroke-dashoffset:0" /><text
       x="1515"
       y="236"
       class="fil1 fnt0"
       id="text413">60</text>
<text
       x="3118.1567"
       y="236"
       class="fil1 fnt0"
       id="text415"
       style="font-size:200.09599304px;font-weight:normal;fill:#000000;font-family:Arial">3</text>
<text
       x="3485.3179"
       y="236"
       class="fil1 fnt0"
       id="text417"
       style="font-size:200.09599304px;font-weight:normal;fill:#000000;font-family:Arial">3</text>
<g
       id="g419"><path
         class="fil2"
         d="M1660 313l0 30 0 0 -71 0 -70 2 -69 2 -67 2 -67 4 -66 4 -64 5 -63 6 -61 7 -59 7 -58 7 -56 9 -55 9 -52 9 -50 10 -48 11 -46 11 -44 12 -41 12 -38 13 -36 13 -34 13 -30 14 -28 14 -25 14 -21 14 -19 15 -15 15 -12 14 -8 14 -5 14 -3 14 -30 -2 4 -20 7 -19 11 -18 14 -18 18 -17 20 -16 23 -16 27 -15 29 -15 32 -14 34 -14 37 -13 39 -13 42 -12 45 -12 46 -11 49 -11 50 -10 53 -10 55 -9 57 -8 58 -8 60 -7 61 -7 64 -6 64 -5 66 -4 67 -4 68 -2 70 -2 70 -2 71 0 0 0zm1282 196l-14 27 -21 -11 -22 -10 -24 -10 -25 -10 -27 -10 -29 -9 -29 -9 -32 -9 -32 -9 -34 -8 -35 -8 -36 -8 -37 -7 -39 -8 -39 -7 -41 -6 -42 -6 -42 -6 -44 -6 -44 -5 -46 -5 -46 -4 -47 -4 -48 -4 -49 -3 -49 -3 -50 -2 -50 -3 -52 -1 -51 -1 -53 -1 -53 0 0 -30 53 0 53 1 52 1 52 2 50 2 51 2 49 3 49 3 48 4 48 4 46 4 46 5 45 5 44 6 43 6 42 6 41 7 40 7 39 7 37 8 37 8 35 8 35 8 32 9 32 9 30 9 29 10 28 10 26 10 25 10 23 11 22 11zm61 49l-87 -2 36 -69 51 71z"
         id="path421" /></g><g
       id="g423"><path
         class="fil2"
         d="M3171 313l0 30 0 0 -6 0 -7 1 -6 2 -6 2 -7 3 -6 4 -6 4 -7 6 -6 5 -6 7 -6 7 -6 8 -6 8 -5 9 -6 10 -5 10 -5 11 -5 11 -4 12 -4 12 -4 13 -4 13 -4 13 -3 14 -2 15 -3 15 -2 15 -2 15 -1 16 -1 15 -1 17 0 16 -30 0 0 -17 1 -17 1 -17 1 -16 2 -16 2 -16 3 -16 3 -15 3 -14 4 -15 4 -14 4 -13 5 -13 5 -13 5 -12 5 -12 6 -11 6 -11 6 -10 7 -10 6 -9 8 -8 7 -8 8 -7 7 -7 9 -5 8 -5 9 -4 9 -4 9 -2 10 -2 9 0 0 0zm159 206l-30 6 -2 -10 -2 -10 -3 -10 -3 -10 -3 -9 -3 -9 -3 -9 -4 -9 -3 -8 -4 -8 -4 -8 -4 -8 -4 -7 -4 -6 -4 -7 -4 -6 -5 -6 -4 -5 -5 -5 -4 -5 -5 -5 -4 -3 -5 -4 -5 -3 -5 -3 -4 -2 -5 -3 -5 -1 -4 -1 -5 -1 -5 -1 -5 0 0 -30 7 0 7 1 7 1 7 2 7 3 7 2 6 4 6 3 6 5 6 4 6 5 6 5 5 6 6 6 5 7 5 6 5 7 5 8 4 7 5 8 4 8 4 9 4 9 4 9 4 9 3 10 4 10 3 10 3 10 3 10 2 11 3 11zm1 78l-54 -68 76 -16 -22 84z"
         id="path425" /></g><g
       id="g427"><path
         class="fil2"
         d="M3532 313l0 30 0 0 -7 0 -6 1 -6 2 -7 2 -6 3 -7 4 -6 4 -6 6 -6 5 -6 7 -6 7 -6 8 -6 8 -6 9 -5 10 -5 10 -5 11 -5 11 -5 12 -4 12 -4 13 -4 13 -3 13 -3 14 -3 15 -2 15 -2 15 -2 15 -2 16 -1 15 0 17 -1 16 -30 0 1 -17 0 -17 1 -17 2 -16 2 -16 2 -16 3 -16 3 -15 3 -14 3 -15 4 -14 5 -13 4 -13 5 -13 5 -12 6 -12 5 -11 6 -11 7 -10 6 -10 7 -9 7 -8 8 -8 7 -7 8 -7 8 -5 9 -5 8 -4 10 -4 9 -2 9 -2 10 0 0 0zm158 206l-29 6 -2 -10 -3 -10 -3 -10 -2 -10 -3 -9 -3 -9 -4 -9 -3 -9 -4 -8 -3 -8 -4 -8 -4 -8 -4 -7 -4 -6 -4 -7 -5 -6 -4 -6 -5 -5 -4 -5 -5 -5 -4 -5 -5 -3 -5 -4 -4 -3 -5 -3 -5 -2 -4 -3 -5 -1 -5 -1 -5 -1 -4 -1 -5 0 0 -30 7 0 7 1 7 1 7 2 7 3 6 2 7 4 6 3 6 5 6 4 6 5 5 5 6 6 5 6 6 7 5 6 4 7 5 8 5 7 4 8 5 8 4 9 4 9 4 9 3 9 4 10 3 10 3 10 3 10 3 10 3 11 2 11zm2 78l-55 -68 76 -16 -21 84z"
         id="path429" /></g><line
       class="fil0 str2"
       x1="3011.4385"
       y1="575"
       x2="3011.4385"
       y2="15.483337"
       id="line405-2"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:10;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:30.0000001, 30.0000001;stroke-dashoffset:0" /><line
       class="fil0 str2"
       x1="3371.3938"
       y1="575"
       x2="3371.3938"
       y2="15.483322"
       id="line405-5"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:10;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:30.0000001, 30.0000001;stroke-dashoffset:0" /><line
       class="fil0 str2"
       x1="3725.554"
       y1="575"
       x2="3725.554"
       y2="15.483324"
       id="line405-5-7"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:10;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:30.0000001, 30.0000001;stroke-dashoffset:0" /></g></svg>
```

I am not familiar with Corel Draw, but I'm guessing that, when you saved the SVG, it gave you the option to embed the font file.  If so, turn that option off if you save other files.